# Increase sleep time after python script executed, while it is running

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, sleep, python-multithreading

I have a simple python code. It makes something and it sleeps x second and it makes another thing again. I want to extend that sleeping time after I execute the file.

For example

```
print("A")
time.sleep(x)
print("B")
```

After I execute the code I want to change and increase the sleeping time before it prints B.

Is it possible? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: store the current sleep value and read it back on re-execution?

Comment: pass the sleep argument as command line argument if it is a script

Comment: Let me clarify. For example sleep time is 5 seconds. I execute the code from terminal. 2 seconds later I want to add 5 seconds more. So it should print "A" and than should wait 10 seconds, finally it should print "B"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is using a list with sleep times you can expand by appending further sleeps while your target function is sleeping. The function `sleep_all` just pops off and executes any sleep available from that list.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Thread, current_thread


def f():
    print(f'{datetime.now()}: A')
    sleep_all()
    print(f'{datetime.now()}: B')


def sleep_all():
    sleeps = current_thread().sleeps
    while sleeps:
        sleep = sleeps.pop()
        print(f'{datetime.now()}: taking a nap for {sleep} s')
        time.sleep(sleep)


if __name__ == '__main__':


    t = Thread(target=f)
    t.sleeps = [5]  # attach instance attribute with sleeps-list
    t.start()
    time.sleep(2)
    print(f'{datetime.now()}: adding another sleep')
    t.sleeps.append(5)
```

Example Output:

```
2018-12-07 22:54:09.733494: A
2018-12-07 22:54:09.733553: taking a nap for 5 s
2018-12-07 22:54:11.735635: adding another sleep
2018-12-07 22:54:14.734963: taking a nap for 5 s
2018-12-07 22:54:19.738833: B

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Version with subclassing `Thread`:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Thread


class Program(Thread):

    def __init__(self, sleep=None):
        super().__init__()
        self._sleeps = [sleep]

    def run(self):
        print(f'{datetime.now()}: A')
        self._sleep_all()
        print(f'{datetime.now()}: B')

    def add_sleep(self, sleep):
        self._sleeps.append(sleep)

    def _sleep_all(self):
        while self._sleeps:
            sleep = self._sleeps.pop()
            print(f'{datetime.now()}: taking a nap for {sleep} s')
            time.sleep(sleep)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    prg = Program(sleep=5)
    prg.start()
    time.sleep(2)
    print(f'{datetime.now()}: adding another sleep')
    prg.add_sleep(sleep=5)
    prg.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

try:
    with open(".sleeptime") as f:
        sleep_time = float(f.read())
except FileNotFoundError:
    sleep_time = 5.0

with open(".sleeptime", "w") as f:
    next_sleep_time = sleep_time + 5.0
    f.write(str(next_sleep_time))

print("A")
time.sleep(sleep_time)
print("B")
```